# Apache Spark unable to find class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'm trying to develop stand alone app using `apache spark` alongside `scala sbt`
I'm getting this error again and again.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
>       at AuctionsApp$.main(AuctionsApp.scala:5)

Here is code snippet.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object AuctionsApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("AuctionsApp")
    println(conf)
  }
}
```

`build.sbt` file

```
name := "AuctionsApp"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.2.0-cdh5.3.2" % "provided"


resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
```

I can navigate to `SparkConf` file by pressing command and click on class name in `import` statement, means that it resides there alongside the other code.

Project build was successful too.

any help is appreciated.

PS. using `IntelliJ Idea CE` version `2016.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in SBT, you specify `provided`, which means the JAR containing the class is assumed to be present on the classpath when the application starts, which isn't the case when debugging locally.

To get around this issue we create an additional project which is meant solely for debugging Spark locally. First, we declare the dependencies on Spark outside of the projects definition:

```
lazy val sparkDeps = Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0-cdh5.3.2"
)
```

Then we create the new project which depends on our main project and `map` over Sparks dependencies and add the `compile` annotation onto the module:

```
lazy val sparkProject = 
  project in file("spark-project")
  .settings(
   // Add your settings and such
  )

lazy val sparkDebugger = project in file("spark-debugger")
  .dependsOn(sparkProject)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= sparkDeps.map(_ % "compile")
)
```

And when we want to debug Spark locally, we make our main method load up from the `sparkDebugger` project in the Debug Configuration window:

[image: Spark Debug Configuration]